# Failing to ssh into server at school

Tags: ssh, fedora

Im trying to ssh into my server at school, but it's not working out.

1. I set a password for my user
2. I generated public and private ssh keys: `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
3. I pinged my school's server, got the IP address
4. Then I tried to copy my keys to it: `ssh-copy-id root@school_server_IP`
5. And then it prompted me for a password... which I KNOW is the
   correct one I'm typing, but it keeps telling me the password is
   wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Terminal]

PS. I'm new to this community, so please let me know if I made an error in this post.

Comment: Should you be using `root` on the remote server, or should you be using your own login name?

Comment: root login may not be allowed on your server's ssh daemon - check /etc/ssh/sshd_config, AllowRootLogin

Comment: @StephenHarris My mistake, my own login name. But before I can log into the server with my credentials, I was under the impression that I had to copy my public ssh key to the server, no? Because ssh matrix.senecac.on.ca doesnt work on it own. It doesnt prompt me for a password and username, iit just says are you sure you wnt to continue connection, yes/no? I select yes, and it prompts me for a password.. which for some reason doesnt work.

Comment: @steve — sounds like that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: Try not to post shots of text if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ssh your-student-name@142.204.140.90` and then update the question with the output/errors.